# Function Template Type Deduction Rules

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have:

```
template<typename ...Ts, typename U, typename=void>
void valid(Ts..., U){}

int main() {
    valid(1.0, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

clang complains:

```
note: candidate function [with Ts = <>, U = double, $2 = void] not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
void valid(Ts..., U){}
     ^
```

And gcc complains:

```
<source>:2:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:5:10: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
    5 |     valid(1.0, 1, 2, 3);
      |     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

According to cling, it seems like the compiler deduces that `Tn` is an empty pack (i.e. <>).  Why is that?  I thought given the argument list (1.0, 1, 2, 3), `U` would be deduced to `int` and `Tn...` would be `double, int, int`.  What are the rules here for the type deduction?

If I changes the caller to:

```
valid<double, int, int>(1.0, 1, 2, 3);
```

It works.  However, if I change it to:

```
valid<double, int, int, int>(1.0, 1, 2, 3);
```

It fails:

```
<source>:2:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:5:33: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 4 provided
    5 |     valid<double, int, int, int>(1.0, 1, 2, 3);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What rules are used here to determine what types I can specify in the type parameter list?

Thanks.

Comment: `Ts...` is a non-deducted context, so template parameter deduction is never going to work for it. Not yet sure why explicitly specified arguments don't work. "**[temp.deduct.type]/5** The non-deduced contexts are: ... **(5.7)** — A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*."

Comment: Ah. "**[temp.deduct.type]/9** ... If *Pi* is a pack expansion, then the pattern of *Pi* is compared with **each remaining argument** in the template argument list of *A*. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by *Pi*." Emphasis mine. In other words, once you start matching a parameter pack, all subsequent arguments are assumed to belong to that parameter pack. So in `valid<double, int, int, int>(1.0, 1, 2, 3)` call, `Ts...` is taken to be four types `{double, int, int, int}`, and then the instantiation expects 5 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

First, why the template argument deduction fails when no template arguments are explicitly specified, as in `valid(1.0, 1, 2, 3)`. This is simple - a parameter pack that's not trailing (not the last in the function parameter list) is non-deduced context:

> **[temp.deduct.type]/5** The non-deduced contexts are:
> ...
> (5.7) — A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*.

---

Second, how explicitly specified template arguments are matched to template parameters, in the presence of a parameter pack. The way it works is, once you get to an argument that corresponds to the pack, all subsequent arguments are taken to be part of that pack.

> **[temp.deduct.type]/9** ... If **P<sub>i</sub>** is a pack expansion, then the pattern of **P<sub>i</sub>** is compared with each remaining argument in the template argument list of **A**. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by **P<sub>i</sub>**.

Thus, `valid<double, int, int>(1.0, 1, 2, 3)` works because `Ts...` is taken to be three types `{double, int, int}`, and `U` is deduced from the fourth argument, `3`. `valid<double, int, int, int>(1.0, 1, 2, 3)` doesn't work because `Ts...` is taken to be four types `{double, int, int, int}`, and then there's no function argument for the last parameter of type `U`.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I got the "non-deduced contexts" part.  For the explicitly specified template argument one, I don't quite get the wordings in the Standard.  Since `Pi` is a pack expansion (in my examples: `double, int, int` and `double, int, int, int`), what `Pi` is "compared" really?  Fail to see what the comparison is....

Comment: `Pi` is the `i`th template parameter, here `Ts...`. `A` is the list of template arguments, here `<double, int, int, int>`